# How to check whether the div is 100 pixels from top and add class to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('.sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('.sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

When the div reaches the top, it adds the class `stick` to it. I want to change is so that when the class reaches **100 px from top**, it should add the class stick. How to achieve that?

Comment: offset window_top or div_top by 100

Comment: Then add `100`: `$('#sticky-anchor').offset().top + 100`.

Comment: I used `$('#sticky-anchor').offset().top + 100` and it did the opposite of what I required so I changed it to `$('#sticky-anchor').offset().top - 100` and it worked perfectly. Cheers @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @AliZia Ah yeah, it would be `- 100` depending on what you want, I was interpreted "from top" as the item being off-screen 100px away from the top. Anyways glad I could help.

Comment: No problem. I got the idea from you and I solved it. Thankyou @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @AliZia That's great, you can add that as a self-answer to your question.

Comment: Done @SpencerWieczorek. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this jQuery,

```
  $(document).on('scroll', function(){
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
          $('#myID').addClass('.myClass');
       }
    });
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/yYqWKN/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
if (window_top > div_top) {
```

To:

```
if (window_top > (div_top+100)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sticky-anchor').offset().top - 100
```

This worked for me.